# how can i get the service from wsdl generated by bepl

Tags: apache-flex, wsdl

i am using flex to finish a browser client which needs to get the web service,

```
     <s:WebService id="wsTest" wsdl="blablabla">

        <s:operation name="?" result="doResault(event)">

            <s:request>

            </s:request>

        </s:operation>

    </s:WebService>
```

but problem comes,because this wsdl is generated by BEPL and i can't see a operation name there,so what should i do?

the wsdl generated by BEPL is listed below,i have deleted many things :
BEPL supposed to be something like a big function,just don't know where is the entrance of bepl and which method i should use

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <wsdl:definitions>
    <wsdl:types>
    ...
    </wsdl:types>

    <wsdl:message name="mainRequest">
        <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="ns:main"/>
    </wsdl:message>
    ...
    <wsdl:portType name="PositioningWebServicePortType">
        <wsdl:operation name="main">
            <wsdl:input message="ns:mainRequest" wsaw:Action="urn:main"/>
        </wsdl:operation>
    <wsdl:operation name="training">
        <wsdl:input message="ns:trainingRequest" wsaw:Action="urn:training"/>
        <wsdl:output message="ns:trainingResponse" wsaw:Action="urn:trainingResponse"/>
        <wsdl:fault message="ns:IOException" name="IOException" wsaw:Action="urn:trainingIOException"/>
        <wsdl:fault message="ns:SQLException" name="SQLException" wsaw:Action="urn:trainingSQLException"/>
    </wsdl:operation>

    </wsdl:portType>

    <wsdl:binding name="PositioningWebServiceSoap11Binding" type="ns:PositioningWebServicePortType">
        <soap:binding transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http" style="document"/>
        <wsdl:operation name="main">
            <soap:operation soapAction="urn:main" style="document"/>
                <wsdl:input>
                    <soap:body use="literal"/>
                </wsdl:input>
            </wsdl:operation>
        <wsdl:operation name="training">
             <soap:operation soapAction="urn:training" style="document"/>
                 <wsdl:input>
                    <soap:body use="literal"/>
                  </wsdl:input>
                  <wsdl:output>
                     <soap:body use="literal"/>
                  </wsdl:output>
        <wsdl:fault name="IOException">
            <soap:fault use="literal" name="IOException"/>
        </wsdl:fault>
        <wsdl:fault name="SQLException">
            <soap:fault use="literal" name="SQLException"/>
        </wsdl:fault>
    </wsdl:operation>


    </wsdl:binding>

    <wsdl:service name="PositioningWebService">

    </wsdl:service>
</wsdl:definitions>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can see the operations or integrate the service in many ways.  Here are a few approaches to get you started:

1) open the URL to the outputted WSDL with a web browser.  You can look through it for all of the operation nodes.  In these nodes you will see the parameters it requires and what to expect in the response.

2) use the data connectivity features in FlashBuilder.  Select your project then choose Data -> Connect to web service... and follow the wizard which will import the WSDL and introspect the service for you.  You will see all the operations etc then.  They can then be used for data binding etc.

Here is a in-depth tutorial on using WSDLs , WebService components and even working with the operations and bindings. http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flex/videotraining/exercises/ex2_05_web.html

Comment: yeah it works for normal wsdl...but when i import a wsdl generated by BEPL(it may be a little different from normal ones),it doesn't work

Comment: ok, a WSDL is supposed to be "standard".  can you paste a link to it.  With a little google searching, I looked at BEPL WSDLs and the ones i saw looked OK.  Maybe there is something non-standard going on.

Comment: yeah that WSDL has tons of omissions and errors in it.  Can you use another tool?  This is definitely a BEPL WSDL problem and not a flex problem.